# Get all admins CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

How can I do a where of the users by role?
I want to bring all the users with the role: `:admin` in the users table.

the fields for the users are generated by the CanCanCan gem, this is my **user.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
...
#  roles_mask             :integer
...

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :glucose_levels
  has_many :foods
  attr_accessor :current_password
  # has_secure_password

  ROLES = %i[patient, doctor]

  def roles=(roles)
    roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with cancancan, you can just do a `User.where(role: 'admin')` assuming `role` is the name of the field in the user table.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the user model

Comment: @MatiasCarpintini. can you update the question with schema for your user table